# Android アプリ作成時、レイアウト段階でエラーが発生してしまう

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

android studioで電卓を作っているのですがレイアウト段階でエラーが発生してしまいます。
私が思うにRelative Layoutらへんだと思うのですがどういじれば治るのかわかりません。
ちなみにこのプログラムは本に書いてあることとほぼ同じプログラムです。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sample.dentaku.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">




         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="数字を入力"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/calcButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:text="計算"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/operationSelecter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calcButton1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/calcButton1"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NumberInput2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NumberInput1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/operationSelecter"
            android:hint="数字を入力"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/calcButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/NumberInput2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/NumberInput2"
            android:text="計算"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calcResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NumberInput2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NumberInput2"
            android:text="=計算結果"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calcButton2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calcResult"
            android:text="続けて計算する"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

         </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: RelativeLayoutの部分]

Comment: 赤く表示される箇所がエラー箇所です。カーソルを当てればエラーの原因が表示されると思うのでご確認ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/activity_vertical_margin'
```

これは参照先がないことによるエラーですが
android studioのバージョンが本を買った時点より新しく、プロジェクト作成時のテンプレートが異なっている事によるエラーだと思います

%ProjectRoot%\app\src\main\res\valuesの下に
ファイルdimens.xmlを作り

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

%ProjectRoot%\app\src\main\resの下に
フォルダvalues-w820dpを、
さらにその下にファイルdimens.xmlを作り

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

と書く事で解決できると思います

Answer (score 0):

エラーの内容がわからないので推測ですが、dimen.xmlファイルが用意されていないのではないでしょうか？

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

これらは`dimen`属性リソースの`activity_****_margin`を指定するという記載です。
指定したリソースを定義していないので、参照するリソースが不明というエラーが発生しているのだと思います。
参考にされている書籍には、その辺りの記述があるのだと思います。

推測があっていればdimen.xmlファイルを作成し、以下のようなパラメータを追加すればエラーは解消されるはずです。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```